# Difference between Environment.Exit and simple return 2 from Main

Tags: .net, exit-code

From outside of the application, is there any difference between

```
...
Environment.Exit(2)
```

and

```
static int Main()
{
    ...
    return 2;
}
```

?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most obvious difference is that you can call Environment.Exit from anywhere in your code. Aside from that:

- Main finishing won't terminate the process if there are other foreground threads executing; `Environment.Exit` will take down the process anyway.
- `Environment.Exit` terminates the process *without* unwinding the stack and executing finally blocks (at least according to my experiments). Obviously when you return from `Main` you're already at the top level as far as managed code is concerned.
- Both give finalizers a chance to execute before the process *really* shuts down
- `Environment.Exit` demands the appropriate security permission, so won't work for less trusted apps.

Having seen the question update, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. In both cases the process will just exit with a code of 2...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713805/net-finalizers-and-exit0 for details about finalization at end of process.

Answer (score 8):

`Environment.Exit(2)` can be used everywhere. `return 2` only within the `Main()` function.

Comment: Updated question - is there any difference from outside of the application?

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a Unit Test and calling Main

```
Program.Main(args);
```

then Environment.exit will always reflect a failure.  Where as using return will work as expect.