# How to get the return value of console app in a batch file?

Tags: c#, batch-file, console

I have a C# console application **AAA.exe** which can return an integer to indicate the result

```
static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    . . .
    if(case1)
       return -1;

    if(case2)
       Environment.Exit(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I will call **AAA.exe** in a batch file and need the return value

```
AAA.exe /p="param1"
```

My question is:

1. how to get the return value of AAA.exe?
2. is there any difference between `return 0;` and `Environment.Exit(0);` statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "errorlevel" in your batch file to get the returned value.  More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743).

Comment: that link is broken.

Comment: If the link was broken before, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any difference between return 0; and Environment.Exit(0);  statements?

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470225/difference-between-environment-exit-and-simple-return-2-from-main)

Answer (score 0):

The environmental variable %ERRORLEVEL% contains the return code of the last executed program or script.

By default, the way to check for the ERRORLEVEL is via the following code.

```
Syntax
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ( 
   DO_Something 
)
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_return_code.htm