# IDisposable.Dispose is never called after exception in using block

Tags: c#, .net, exception, idisposable, using-statement

I understand from many sources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518352/does-dispose-still-get-called-when-exception-is-thrown-inside-of-a-using-stateme) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that the `Dispose` method of an `IDisposable` will always be called if an exception is thrown in a `Using` block. So then I have this code:

```
static class MainEntryPoint
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleUnhandledException;

        using (var x = new Disposable())
        {
            throw new Exception("asdfsdf");
        }
    }

    private static void HandleUnhandledException(Object sender, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("I am disposed");
    }
}
```

It exits the application when an un-handled exception is thrown. The `Dispose` method is never called. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Environment.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) will terminate the program

> If Exit is called from a try or catch block, the code in any finally
>   block does  not execute. If the return statement is used, the code in
>   the finally block does execute.

```
using (var x = new Disposable())
{
    throw new Exception("asdfsdf");
}
```

will be converted to

```
Disposable x = new Disposable();
try
{
    throw new Exception("asdfsdf");
}
finally
{
    if (x != null)
        x.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yes, using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you had added a finalizer to `Disposable`, like:

```
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am disposed");

        if (disposing)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    ~Disposable()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

(so using the "full" `IDisposable` pattern), then "normally" the finalizer would be called (because the finalizers have a chance to run on `Environment.Exit`), and that method would call `Dispose(bool disposing)`. Note that even here there is the possibility that the finalizer wouldn't be run, because there is a time limit for them to run, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713895/613130).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly! there is no way the code in the Dispose method will be called since Environment.Exit(0) has been called in the event handler.

Try to remove the call to Environment.Exit(0) and see if the Debug.Print() is called.